# Why does a PreferenceActivity recycles the SwitchPreferences despite they all fit in the screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app's settings which is a PreferenceActivity has 3 preferences all of which are SwitchPreferences.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <SwitchPreference>
           ....
    </SwitchPreference>
    <SwitchPreference>
           ....
    </SwitchPreference>
    <SwitchPreference>
           ....
    </SwitchPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I was solving a different issue, during which I observed that clicking on any switch recycles all the views though all the views fit in the screen.

My question here is why does this happen, because as far as I know, recycling happens when the views get out of screen limits!

Answer (score 0):

Recycling happens when the ListView refreshes, which will occur in a PreferenceActivity whenever a value changes. It's normal, don't worry about it.